# Editing distance between tick marks

Tags: matlab

I am currently using subplots in `MATLAB` and this is my x tick mark data:`[.4 .5 .6 .9 1.2 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 15 20 30 40]`

I am trying to determine if there is a way to space the tick marks evenly, or expand the spacing for the lower values so you can actually read the numbers. In short I would like the physical spacing of the tick marks to be based on some predetermined constant and not the actual numerical values.

Comment: `set(gca,'xtick', [somenumbersyoulike])`. Just  put whatever you like in that vector.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I mean when you look at the actual plot .4 and .5 are so close together, you cant actually read the numbers, so the ticks still need to be .4 and .5, but they need to be further apart.

Comment: I hope you realise that this last sentence is a contradiction. They can not be in a location, and in another location, both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use logarythmic scale for x-axis - use `semilogx` instead of `plot`.
(IMO this would be better in your case)

```
x = [.4 .5 .6 .9 1.2 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 15 20 30 40];
y = x/2; % some example data
figure
semilogx(x,y, '.')
set(gca,'xtick', x)
```

Another option is to change labels on x-ticks setting `xticklabel` property. Note that you can set custom values in `ticks` vector.

```
x = [.4 .5 .6 .9 1.2 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 15 20 30 40];
y = x/2; % some example data
ticks = [];
for t = 1:size(x,2)
  ticks = [ticks t];
end
figure
plot(ticks, y, '.') % in this example same as 'plot(y)'
set(gca, 'xtick', ticks,'xticklabel', {.4 .5 .6 .9 1.2 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 15 20 30 40})
```